# Iterate over a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

How to achieve the following traversal over a dictionary?

```
a = {'Source_1': [1, 2], 'Source_2': [7, 8, 9, 10], 'Source_3': [11, 12, 13, 14]...}

If Source_1 takes 1, Source_2 takes 7, Source_3 takes 11, ..., do something
If Source_1 takes 1, Source_2 takes 7, Source_3 takes 12, ..., do something
If Source_1 takes 1, Source_2 takes 7, Source_3 takes 13, ..., do something
  ... etc
If Source_1 takes 2, Source_2 takes 10, Source_3 takes 14, ..., do something
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, could you clean up your code and add details as of the output your are expecting?

Comment: It may help to post the code you have so far.

Comment: What do you mean by "takes"? `Source_1` is mapped to a list containing 1 and 2. Do you want to check if the value of another variable `x` is *contained* in `a['Source_1']`?

Comment: Or do you want something like `for x in itertools.product(*a.values()): do_something(x)`?

Comment: I have an optimization problem with uncertainties. The keys of the dictionary a give the names of these uncertainties, i.e., the locators of uncertainties in my model). The values of dictionary give all the possible outcomes of these uncertainties. For each outcome, I solve a distinct optimization problem. For example, consider the following optimization problem, F(\xi, \mu) = Min (\xi * x + \mu * y), in which \xi and \mu are random variables, x and y are decision variables. Then dictionary a is like {"x" : [1,2], "y": [3,4,5] }. I need to solve F(1,3), F(1,4), F(1,5)...F(2,5) respectively.

Comment: Do you mean **contains** by "takes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to do is iterate over all combinations of elements contained in your values, then `itertools.product` is the equivalent of a nested for-loop of arbitrarly depth.

```
import itertools

a = {'Source_1': [1, 2], 'Source_2': [3, 4], 'Source_3': [5]}

for x in itertools.product(*a.values()):
    print(x)
```

Which prints:

```
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 4, 5)
```

Although note that **prior to Python 3.6, dictionary values are not ordered**. This means the output above may not be well-defined.

So if you are using a version prior to the above, a dictionary is probably the wrong choice of data structure.

Although, if you are commited to using a dictionary, you can sort your values in the order you want them to appear. By example if you want them to be sorted by your dictionary keys, the following will ensure you get the correct ordering.

```
for x in itertools.product(*map(lambda x: x[1], sorted(a.items()))):
    print(x)
```

Comment: It will be in Python 3.7, though (and is in Python 3.6 if you are using CPython).

Comment: @J.Lin Are you using Python 3.6+?

Comment: To get the order correct you could get the values explicitly with their key's: `src1, src2, src3 = a['Source_1'],a['Source_2'],a['Source_3'],` Then get the product.

Comment: @chepner I am trying to make it usable for Python 3+. Any way to fix the problem?

Comment: @J.Lin What I am saying is that prior to Python 3.6, you **cannot** iterate through keys in the order they were created, Python just could not do it prior to 3.6.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I see. Maybe I shouldn't use dictionaries at the very beginning.

Comment: @J.Lin Yes, if you can avoid using a dictionary, then that would be the best. although, if this is not possible, I updated my answer to provide a fix.

Comment: You could do something like `product(*itemgetter('Source_1', 'Source_2', 'Source_3')(a))` to ensure the values are returned in the correct order. (`itemgetter` must be imported from the `operator` module.) Or, you can use an `OrderedDict` instead of a regular dict.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon It solves my problem. Thx!

Comment: @chepner Thank you for additional nice solutions!